# Runtime query analysis and optimization

Tags: mysql, database, performance, runtime, query-optimization

I'm wondering if there's some sort of runtime mechanism that would observe the queries that are running against my database server; record how many queries of each "type" are running; look at the performance of these queries; then, based on this runtime data, suggest what indexes need to be added/removed.

I'm working against MySQL at the moment; if you know of similar tools for other DB vendors, I'd be interested to know, too. Thanks!!

Comment: I answered then realised you mentioned MySQL!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest giving [Jet Profiler](http://www.jetprofiler.com/) a try. The free version is a bit limited but i still found it useful. It will do most of what you have asked, but you may struggle to find a tool that will suggest indexes for you though.

Comment: Just gave it a shot... Looks very promising! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

how about the [New MySQL Query Profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) (since 5.0.37)? google has [some more](http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+profiler).